# Non-static reference to static in Java (but I'm only using static)

Tags: java, methods, static, non-static

I'm getting the following errors when this code runs:
Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field c
Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field d
This happens 11 times total with the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class problemStatement
{
  int c = 0, d = 0;
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enters two integers - 0 0 to end program");
    do
    {
      c = in.nextInt();
      d = in.nextInt();
      System.out.print("User input: " + c + " " + d + " " + displayValues);
      if (isFinished(c,d))
      {
        System.out.println("End of Program.");
      }
      else
      {
        displayValues (c,d);
      }
    }while(!isFinished(c,d));
  }
  public static int min ( int a, int b)
  {
    if ( a >=b)
    {
      return b;
    }
    else
    {
      return a;
    }
  }
  public static int max ( int a, int b)
  {
    if ( a >=b)
    {
      return a;
    }
    else
    {
      return b;
    }
  }
  public static boolean isFinished ( int a, int b )
  {
    if (a==0&&b==0)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
    public static void displayValues ( int a, int b )
    {
      int e = min(a,b);
      int f = max(a,b);
      System.out.print("Max value: " + e + " Min value: " + f);
    }
  }
```

I agree some of the code is redundant, however, I'm a newbie and this is to so I can learn more about Java.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you attempt to put the error text in a search engine and read the results?

Comment: What are `c` and `d`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes i did, but I couldn't find anything related to my specific issue, they are all related to actually referencing a static using a non-static, but all of my methods are static

Comment: @Mr_Wizerman69 All your methods may be static, but the variables you are calling are not.

Comment: It's because `c` and `d` can be used only on instance, not class. Make them static and it will work. Or do `s = new problemStatement()` and access `s.c`.

Comment: I suppose c and d should be declared within `main` method, not as (no-static) member variables.

Comment: -1 for failing to research first cuz this is common error

Comment: @KickButtowski He did research it, apparently.  He didn't know exactly what words to put into the search engine.  _We_ know what terms to look for since we already know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simon is correct. Another approach is to define c and d inside of main. Something like

```
  int c = in.nextInt();
  int d = in.nextInt();
```

This gives better scoping.

Comment: I'll definitely try this, it makes sense here so I'll let you know if it works, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your variables `c` and `d` are instance variables (non-static). In order to access them, you need to have an instance of `problemStatement` class. So either you make them `static` or you create an `instance = new problemStatement()` and access them by `instance.c` and `instance.d`.

In your case I would make everything `static`.

Comment: Please allow me too disagree: variables c and d are only used within main(), so they should be declared in main! Making them static is somewhat evil...

Comment: You are right. The code is not object-oriented, so using class variables here doesn't make much sense. Going with local variables is a better solution.

Comment: Thanks Simon. So what you're suggesting is type c = new problemStatment() and d = new problemStatment()?

Comment: **what is ordinary variables?** did you mean Class Variables ?

Comment: See the answer of user1879313.